# Include jQuery in Chrome Extension Inject.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have an inject.js that executes as soon as my Extension's icon is clicked.

It's invoked with:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'js/inject.js'}, () => {
    // We don't need to inject code everwhere
    // for example on chrome:// URIs so we just
    // catch the error and log it as a warning.
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.warn(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
  });
```

It's making an API call:

```
     chrome.storage.sync.get(['atsmap'], function(result) {
if (result.atsmap) {
        let requestObj2 = {
            ID: result.atsmap
        }
       $.get('https://myURL', requestObj2, (data2, status2) => {
           console.log(data2);
        })
    }
     });
```

Because the options.html page (which includes a reference to jquery) hasn't rendered at this point, jQuery is undefined:

> Error in response to storage.get: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Is there a way to load jquery.min.js before the inject.js gets called?

Comment: While there was likely a better solution, I simply copied all of an unminified jQuery file to the top of my code.

Comment: Simply use another executeScript before the first one, and put your original code in its callback.